# Will setting "noImplicitAny" in typescript to false disable typechecking?

Tags: typescript

Typescript adds many features on top of javascript es6 and I am interested in *static typing* and the *private/public/protected keywords.*

The biggest limitation that is imposed by the Typescript compiler so far is the inability to use javascript libraries that do not have type definition files(`.d.ts`).

We were able to compile against a library([cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio)) without type definitions by setting the `"noImplicitAny"` option to `false`, but I am concerned that this will allow *implicit any* in our project's code.

cheerio as well as many other javascript libraries already have type definitions thanks to the [DefinitlyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) project but I can't predict when we will need a javascript library without available type definitions.

When the need will come we will have to set `"noImplicitAny"` to `false`. **Will this effectively disable some or all of the compile time type-checking?**

Comment: Even if library doesn't have type definitions you don't have to set `noImplicitAny` to `false`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy to write a type-definition for a library that doesn't have type definitions ([example](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13348#issuecomment-271432232)):

```
// somelib.d.ts
declare module "somelib" {
  const lib: any;
  export = lib;
}
```

Now you can import the module and use it however you like without type-check errors, without losing type-checking elswhere:

```
import * as somelib from "somelib";
somelib.doSomething();
```

You can apparently even write a [catch-all wildcard for all libraries](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13348#issuecomment-282388407) (I haven't tried this personally):

```
declare module "*";
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `noImplicitAny` you might want to use [`--skipLibCheck`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#new---skiplibcheck) since it is more appropriate for your case.

Comment: That really depends on what errors he encounters with the definition files. But it's an interesting option :)

Answer (score 2):

If you specify types, this option will not impact the checking Typescript does on symbols that have types defined.

Setting this option will cause the compiler to asume you meant `any` where you don't explicitly specify a type:

```
function log(someArg) { // someArgs will be assumed to be any
  sendDataToServer(someArg);
}

var x; // x is any;
```

Since `any` can be assigned to any other type, there is a class of errors you can run into. If you don't specify the type for a variable for example, you can use that variable anywhere regardless of expected type:

```
var x; // x is any implicitly ;
x = 10
function foo(a: string) {
    a.split(',');
}

foo(x); // Ok, any can be assigned to string    
var bar: Date = x; // Ok any can also be Date
```

More info in [noImplicitAny](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/options/noImplicitAny.html)