# ngx-confirm giving the error on importing into the TS file

Tags: angular

On following the simple tutorial https://github.com/akmittal/ngx-confirm#ngxconfirm in the existing project, Gives me error on importing the following into the component.ts file

```
import { NgxConfirmModule } from 'ngx-confirm/ngx-confirm.module';
```

The error message in the browser with the black bacground  is the following

```
 in [at-loader] ./node_modules/ngx-confirm/ngx-confirm.component.ts:32:3 
TS7008: Member 'confirmModal' implicitly has an 'any' type.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/ngx-confirm/ngx-confirm.component.ts:49:5 
TS2322: Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Confirm'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/ngx-confirm/ngx-confirm.component.ts:55:5 
TS2322: Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Confirm'
```

I couldn't found about this in anywhere.

Comment: please post tsconfig.ts

Answer (score 0):

Check `noImplicitAny` value in your `tsconfig` file.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false // <-----
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Set it to false to workaround this error.

Answer (score 0):

Before you disable noImplicitAny for the entire app, just because one small dependency lacks the proper typing, try these options:

1. add `"skipLibCheck": true` to tsconfig.json `compilerOptions`.
2. stub out typings for `ngx-confirm.module`, by following the advice listed here: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48790309/will-setting-noimplicitany-in-typescript-to-false-disable-typechecking)

In typings.d.ts add:

```
declare module 'ngx-confirm' {
  const lib: any;
  export = lib;
}
```

Comment: I couldn't understand the solution its very generalized. Do, I have to use all the statements in my component.ts file ? I'm comparatively new to Angular .